# Is there any DCC algorithm implemented in Veins?

Tags: veins

I learned from the Veins website that Veins relies on IEEE 802.11p and 1609.4 which does not mandate a DCC mechanism. I am wondering if any DCC algorithm is still implemented in Veins except using 3rd party models?

Answer (score 0):

As of Veins 5.0, no "standard" ETSI Decentralized Congestion Control (DCC) model is included with Veins. If you are looking for a set of models that focuses on the ETSI stack, you might find the https://github.com/riebl/artery project interesting.

Comment: Christoph, when you mean there is no "standard" DCC model is included do you still mean that there is "some" kind of DCC implemented? if so, could you please point to the source code?

Comment: I am not aware of a publicly available version, but there have been a number of papers that used a custom implementation of ETSI DCC (see, for example, https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Veins+ETSI+DCC); when I talked to authors at conferences they claimed that all of ETSI DCC took "no more than an afternoon" to implement.